# Sql, choose number from string

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Is it possible in mysql/mariadb choose number from String? Required number is between "-" and "/".

Table products:

```
|   id       |   product  |   code                     |
|------------|------------|----------------------------|
|   124      |   CubeA    |   SVS-6/2020-St            |
|   221      |   CubeB    |   SVS-46/2020-St           |
|   138      |   PrismA   |   UIS-KO-OVKS-260/2022-St  |
|   126      |   PrismB   |   UIS-KO-OVKS-3/2022-St    |
```

Required output:

```
|   id       |   product  |   code                     |   output   |
|------------|------------|----------------------------|------------|
|   126      |   PrismB   |   UIS-KO-OVKS-3/2022-St    |     3      |
|   124      |   CubeA    |   SVS-6/2020-St            |     6      |
|   221      |   CubeB    |   SVS-46/2020-St           |    46      |
|   138      |   PrismA   |   UIS-KO-OVKS-260/2022-St  |   260      |
```

I tried something, but not successfully.
These queries are not working. Column output is empty.

```
SELECT id, 
       product, 
       code, 
       SUBSTR(code, 1, INSTR(code, ' ') - 1) AS output
FROM products
ORDER BY output ASC
```

```
SELECT id, 
       product, 
       code, 
       REGEXP_REPLACE(SUBSTR(code, 1, INSTR(code, ' ') - 1), '[[:alpha:]]','') AS output
FROM products
ORDER BY output ASC
```

I use mariadb 2.5.5.

[SUBSTRING](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/substring/),

[INSTR](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/instr/),

[REGEXP_REPLACE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regexp_replace/)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: `substring_index(substring_index(code,'/',1),'-',-1)`

Comment: And is it possible convert string to number in column output? Because when are string 10, 6, 7. At first row is 10, but should be 6. `DECIMAL()` doesn't work.

Comment: Just do `order by 0+output`

Comment: I doesn't work. `ORDER BY 0+output ASC`. Result is in first row 86, 120, 50, 252, 146, 206 and in last row 100. I use MariaDB.

Comment: With this `CAST(substring_index(substring_index(code,'/',1),'-',-1) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS output` it is work. [CAST](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/cast/)

Comment: Question can be marked as solved.